# How to give access to multiple users for same row in Data Studio for databases other than BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, looker-studio

To enable row level security, I used `Filter By Email` option as suggested [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766?hl=en). But I want to know can I enable access to same row for multiple users and also how to enable super users who can see all rows. For example if below is the sample data then I want to have different output based on who is logged in.

```
userId  age email
A       20  usera@gmail.com
B       15  userb@gmail.com
C       25  userc@gmail.com
Z       30  admin@gmail.com
```

**When A is logged in**

```
userId  age email
A       20  usera@gmail.com
```

**When B is logged in**

```
userId  age email
A       20  usera@gmail.com
B       15 userb@gmail.com
```

**When Z is logged in**

```
userId  age email
A       20  usera@gmail.com
B       15  userb@gmail.com
C       25  userc@gmail.com
Z       30  admin@gmail.com
```

Update1 : I am using postgres instance for reporting (not bigQuery), so solution which make use of `@DS_USER_EMAIL` will not work

Comment: How do you know that user B can see the row A and B? and A only the A? Where are located these rules?

Comment: I will have a mapping table for that. But atleast is it possible to have a superuser who can see all data even when filter by email is on. I will have a list of some emails and if they are logged in then they should be able to see all rows. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The filter by email simply provide you the email of the current logged user. You have to use it to filter your query. I designed a simple test like this

```
with sample as (
  select "a" as userId, 10 as age, "usera@gmail.com" as email
  UNION ALL
  select "b" as userId, 20 as age, "userb@gmail.com" as email
  UNION ALL
  select "c" as userId, 30 as age, "userc@gmail.com" as email
), auth as (
  select "usera@gmail.com" as user, "usera@gmail.com" as permission
  UNION ALL
  select "userb@gmail.com" as user, "usera@gmail.com" as permission
  UNION ALL
  select "userb@gmail.com" as user, "userb@gmail.com" as permission
  UNION ALL
  select "admin@gmail.com" as user, ".*" as permission
)
select * from sample
where REGEXP_CONTAINS(email,(select STRING_AGG(permission,"|") from auth where auth.user = @DS_USER_EMAIL))
```

I have the `sample` table with your data. I created a `auth` table with the link between the user email and the view authorization.

In the final request, I use a regex to check if the row is authorized or not. The admin has the value `.*` to view all the data. The other is simple an aggregation of all the rows, separated by a pipe `|` (OR in regex language)

**EDIT**

The power of BigQuery is the compliance with the SQL2011 standard, and a working query in postgres is similar. For the regex pattern use [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html). *Look at the admin regex pattern, it's not regex conventional, but it works*

[`string_agg` is an existing function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/)

```
with sample as (
  select 'a' as userId, 10 as age, 'usera@gmail.com' as email
  UNION ALL
  select 'b' as userId, 20 as age, 'userb@gmail.com' as email
  UNION ALL
  select 'c' as userId, 30 as age, 'userc@gmail.com' as email
), auth as (
  select 'usera@gmail.com' as user, 'usera@gmail.com' as permission
  UNION ALL
  select 'userb@gmail.com' as user, 'usera@gmail.com' as permission
  UNION ALL
  select 'userb@gmail.com' as user, 'userb@gmail.com' as permission
  UNION ALL
  select 'admin@gmail.com' as user, '%' as permission
)
select * from sample
where email SIMILAR TO (select STRING_AGG(permission,'|') from auth where auth.user = @DS_USER_EMAIL)
```

**The query works, but it's not usable with Datastudio because the `@DS_USER_EMAIL` exists only with BigQuery**

The workaround is to use [Cloud SQL federated query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries). And the final request is a mix between both db engine

```
with sample as (
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("gbl-imt-homerider-basguillaueb.us.vertx-postgres", """ select 'a' as userId, 10 as age, 'usera@gmail.com' as email
  UNION ALL
  select 'b' as userId, 20 as age, 'userb@gmail.com' as email
  UNION ALL
  select 'c' as userId, 30 as age, 'userc@gmail.com' as email""")), auth as (
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("gbl-imt-homerider-basguillaueb.us.vertx-postgres", """ select 'usera@gmail.com' as user, 'usera@gmail.com' as permission
  UNION ALL
  select 'userb@gmail.com' as user, 'usera@gmail.com' as permission
  UNION ALL
  select 'userb@gmail.com' as user, 'userb@gmail.com' as permission
  UNION ALL
  select 'admin@gmail.com' as user, '.*' as permission"""))
select * from sample
where REGEXP_CONTAINS(email,(select STRING_AGG(permission,"|") from auth where auth.user = @DS_USER_EMAIL))
```

Comment: While this will work but I was hoping if google has a better implementation of row level security. Using `IN` clause with `Regex` might degrade performance of reports.

Comment: I realised that solution that you provided will only work with BigQuery. In my case, I am using a google cloud sql postgres instance as backend database. So `@DS_USER_EMAIL` will not work there. I have updated my question to add missing detail of non bigquery solution.

Comment: Ok, a direct use of DS_USER_EMAIL is not possible with Postgres, but you can use BigQuery anyway!! Not the most powerful, but it's working.

Comment: we are using postgres as OLTP and data volume is not much to make a move to BigQuery so wanted to power some reports using postgres itself.

Comment: There is no move to BigQuery! It's BigQuery engine that use the external connexion to query the data in PostGres and to present them to Datastudio. No move, no replication, no latency. Only one constraint: it works only with Cloud SQL. If you host your own Postgres database elsewhere, you can't